# Can't install or update any nuget packages in my project in vs2017

Tags: c#, nuget-package

When I used vs2015, packages were added to a packages folder in my solution and a package.config file was added and also reference includes in the csproj file. But since I use vs2017 I'm not able to install or update any nuget packages, although the packages are downloaded and unzipped in this location:

C:\Users\user.nuget\packages:

[packages](https://i.postimg.cc/8PkfVp0C/log2.png)

I tried both Manage Nuget Packages and Package Manager Console, but I get the errors "Install failed. Rolling back." and "Could not add reference, dll not registered." I tried installing webview2, newtonsoft json and restsharp but get the same errors.
Here's the output:

[output packetmanager](https://i.postimg.cc/13QvcNCz/log.png)

So how can I download and unzip a package into a package folder in my solution and install it in my project ?

Comment: The entire ecosystem spent years migrating away from `package.config`, so should you, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference

Comment: @Lex Li
I still am not able to install the package in my project.

Comment: You'd better open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com to have someone thoroughly analyze the setup on your machine. NuGet changed too much in the past few years, so you might need some patches here and there. It is impossible to suggest anything without seeing your machine.

Comment: @Lex Li I managed to add a packagereference node to my csproj and manually add webview core & webview winform dll references to my folder. But I still get an error that the webview core dll isn't registered. Any idea what to do ?